# java regex pattern string format

Tags: java, regex

I am exploring Regular expressions.

*Problem statement :* *Replace String between # and # with the values provided in replacements map*.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RegExTest {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        HashMap<String,String> replacements = new HashMap<String,String>();
        replacements.put("OldString1","NewString1");
        replacements.put("OldString2","NewString2");
        replacements.put("OldString3","NewString3");

        String source = "#OldString1##OldString2#_ABCDEF_#OldString3#";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\#(.+?)\\#");
        //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\#\\#");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, "");
            buffer.append(replacements.get(matcher.group(1)));            
        }
        matcher.appendTail(buffer);
        System.out.println("OLD_String:"+source);
        System.out.println("NEW_String:"+buffer.toString());

    }
}
```

Output: ( *Caters to my requirement but does not know who group(1) command works)*

```
OLD_String:#OldString1##OldString2#_ABCDEF_#OldString3#
NEW_String:NewString1NewString2_ABCDEF_NewString3
```

If I change the code as below

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\#(.+?)\\#");
```

with

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\#\\#");
```

I am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
```

I did not understand difference between

```
"\\#(.+?)\\#" and `"\\#\\#"`
```

Can you explain the difference?

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html             might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is fairly straightforward - `\\#(.+?)\\#` will match two hashes with one or more chars between them, while `\\#\\#` will match two hashes next to each other.

A more powerful question, to my mind, is "what is the difference between `\\#(.+?)\\#` and `\\#.+?\\#`?"

In this case, what's different is what is (or isn't) getting captured. Brackets in a regex indicate a *capture group* - basically, some substring you want to output separately from the overall matched string. In this case, you're capturing the text in between the hashes - the first pattern will capture and output it separately, while the second will not. Try it yourself - asking for `matcher.group(1)` on the first will return that text, while the second will produce an exception, even though they both match the same text.

Answer (score 0):

.+? Tells it to match (one or more of) anything lazily (until it sees a #). So as soon as it parses one instance of something, it stops.

I think the \#\# would match ## so i think the error is because it only matches that one ## and then there's only a group 0, no group 1. But not 100% on that part.